# Mp4 ( created by concatenating two mp4 using ffmpeg) not playing in html5 video tag

Tags: php, html, ffmpeg, html5-video

I am getting trouble to play mp4 file in video tag of html5.

I have two mp4 files on my server.
I use following code.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
<source src="input.mp4" type='video/mp4 '/>
</video>
```

This works fine.
After that I am concatenating two mp4 using ffmpeg.
Code for concatenating as follows.

```
exec('ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -qscale:v 1 intermediate1.mpg');
exec('ffmpeg -i input2.mp4 -qscale:v 1 intermediate2.mpg');
exec('cat intermediate1.mpg intermediate2.mpg | ffmpeg -f mpeg -i - -vcodec copy -acodec copy intermediate_all.mpg');
exec('ffmpeg -y -i intermediate_all.mpg -an -pass 1 -threads 2 $options temp.mp4');
exec('ffmpeg -y -i intermediate_all.mpg -acodec libfaac -ar 44100 -ab 96k -pass 2 -threads 2 $options temp.mp4');
exec('qt-faststart temp.mp4 new_output.mp4');
```

This conversion works good.
I can play this file using every player but when I use this converted file in video tag It doesn't work.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are transcoding to mpeg2 and then trying to put mpeg2 back in the mp4 container. Is that intended?

Comment: Will the video file play if you drop it directly into a Chrome browser window?

Comment: What browsers are you trying this?

Comment: @BlueVoodoo yes as per ffmpeg documentation i convert it into mpg then concatenate and then convert back to mp4.

Comment: @TimHayes not it didn't work when I directly drop it in chrome.

Comment: @d33pika I am trying with chrome. I think it's not a browser issue because before converting it works on same browser.

Comment: @d33pika No chrome doesn't support .mpg file. That's why I am converting mpg file into mp4 file.

Comment: then what do you mean by "I think it's not a browser issue because before converting it works on same browser."

Comment: I have two mp4 files which are working on chrome. Then I am converting those files to mpg format and concatenate them. After that I convert back mpg to mp4.

Comment: You might try taking a look at the file through ffprobe. http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
    <source src="input.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
</video>
```

(type='video/mp4', ' has to be ").

Comment: No, you don't have to use double quotes here. Single quotes are just fine.